# Parsing xml insert into a SQLite db and show data in a Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, xml-parsing, android-sqlite

I have parsed a `xml` which it works but now I want to store data in a `SQLite db` because this is a local for every phone.
I want to insert this data of `xml` in db and then load the data from db.
I don't know how to create a SQLite db which will retrieve data and I can save there new entry.

This is my code `Bookmark.class`.

> Bookmark.class

```
public class Bookmark {
    String name, id, nativeUrl, searchUrl;
    int icon;
    int viewType;


    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIcon() { return icon; }
    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNativeUrl() {
        return nativeUrl;
    }

    public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
    }

    public String getSearchUrl() {
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }
    public int getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookmark{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
                ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

This is the `Adapter.class`

> Adapter.class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = null;
        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.add_bookmark, parent, false);
            return new ButtonViewHolder(view);
        }else {
            return  null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
       //     viewHolder.tvId.setText(arrayList.get(position).getId());
            viewHolder.tvSearchUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl());
            viewHolder.tvNativeUrl.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNativeUrl());

        } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            ButtonViewHolder buttonViewHolder = (ButtonViewHolder) holder;
            buttonViewHolder.imgButton.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // based on you list you will return the ViewType 
        if (arrayList.get(position).getViewType() == 0) {
            return ITEM_TYPE_ONE;
        } else {
            return ITEM_TYPE_TWO;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvName, tvId, tvSearchUrl, tvNativeUrl;

        ImageView tvIcon;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tvIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
//            tvId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
            tvSearchUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSiteURL);
            tvNativeUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNativeUrl);
            // tvName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
    }

    public class ButtonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        ImageView imgButton;

        public ButtonViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imgButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_button_add);

            imgButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityChangeBookmark.class);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

This is the `Fragment.class` which I show the parsed `xml`.

> Fragment.class

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    View paramView;
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        myRecyclerView =  paramView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        // myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"),"drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);

                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);
       return paramView;
    }
    }
```

This is the `.XML`

```
<Bookmarks>
    <Bookmark name="Bing" hidden="" icon="bing" id="0" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://www.bing.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Google"  hidden="true" icon="google" id="1" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://www.google.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Youtube" hidden="" icon="youtube" id="2" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="http://m.youtube.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Facebook" hidden="" icon="facebook" id="3" nativeUrl="facebook://" searchUrl="https://m.facebook.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Twitter" hidden="" icon="twitter" id="4" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://mobile.twitte.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Instagram" hidden="" icon="instagram" id="5" nativeUrl="instagram://" searchUrl="https://instagram.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Gmail" hidden="" icon="gmail" id="6" nativeUrl="googlemail://" searchUrl="https://gmail.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Translate" hidden="" icon="google_translate" id="7" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://" />
    <Bookmark name="Amazon" hidden="" icon="amazon" id="8" nativeUrl="" searchUrl="https://www.amazon.com" />
    <Bookmark name="Wikipedia" hidden=""  icon="wiki" id="9"  searchUrl="http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page" />
    <Bookmark name="Weather" hidden="" icon="weathercom" id="10" searchUrl="http://weather.com" />
    <Bookmark name="eBay" hidden="" id="9" icon="ebay"  searchUrl="http://ebay.to/1VPVeAs" />
    <Bookmark name="Apple" id="10" icon="apple"  searchUrl="http://www.apple.com" hidden="true" />
</Bookmarks>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an SQLite Database you first design it (determine the data you want to be stored and from this the tables and columns into which that data is to be stored).

From the XML it appears that you would want the following data to be stored:-

1. **name** as a String (which equates to TEXT for SQLite)
2. **hidden** as a boolean (SQLite doesn't have a type for boolean so INTEGER could be used)
3. **icon** as TEXT
4. **id** AS INTEGER
5. **nativeurl** as TEXT
6. **searchurl** as TEXT

These will be the columns and bookmark would appear to be a natural choice for the table name (for ease the assumption is that a single table will suit).

Ideally you would do more in-depth analysis of the data and requirements, such as constraints and indexes. However, for ease of demonstration the assumption will be that **id** (as it probably means that it **id**entifies a single set of the above (a row))

As a summary it sounds like you want a TABLE named bookmark that has 6 columns with column **id** (which we will call **_id** (sometimes in Android this can be required)) making up the PRIMARY KEY. The other columns as above.

To create such a table you need to create the SQL required to tell SQLite to CREATE the table. The following would suit :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookmark (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, hidden INTEGER, icon TEXT, nativeurl TEXT, searchurl TEXT);
```

However, you can't just run the above. You first need a database in which the table (there can be many tables in a database) will reside.

The typical (but not the only way) way create a database in Android is to utilise the **SQLiteOpenHelper** class, for which you must create a subclass. Along the lines of `class yourOpenHelper extends SQliteOpenHelper { ......... }`.

You are required to override two methods **onCreate** and **onUpgrade**
- onCreate runs when the database is first created (***note onCreate only runs once for the lifetime of the database***). The database will appear to have no tables at this point. So this is typically where you'd create the table(s).
- onUpgragde runs when the 4th parameter passed to the super constructor is increased (below the constant DBVERSION is used for this value).

It is highly advisable to use constants for table and column names and to then always use those constants. From the above you could have (as an example) :-

```
public class BookmarkDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "bookmarks.db"; // The name of the database file
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;  // The Database version

    public static final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
    public static final String COl_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COl_HIDDEN = "hidden";
    public static final String COL_ICON = "icon";
    public static final String COL_NATIVEURL = "nativeurl";
    public static final String COL_SEARCHURL = "searchurl";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public BookmarkDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        // Forces creation of the database (if it doesn't already exist)
        // and stores it when the BookmarkDBHelpr is instantiated
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * This creates the table(s) NOTE only automatically runs once
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // The SQL to be used to create the table
        String crt_bookmark_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BOOKMARK + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_HIDDEN + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_ICON + " TEXT, " +
                COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT," +
                COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_bookmark_tbl_sql); // CREATE THE TABLE

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    /**
     * Adds a row
     */
    public long addBookMark(long id, String name, boolean hidden, String icon, String nativeurl, String searchurl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_ID,id); // NOTE will not insert if id already exists.
        cv.put(COl_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COl_HIDDEN,hidden);
        cv.put(COL_ICON,icon);
        cv.put(COL_NATIVEURL,nativeurl);
        cv.put(COL_SEARCHURL,searchurl);
        // uses the convenience insert method that builds the SQL
        return mDB.insert(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
    }

    /**
     * Example of extracting data from the database
     */
    public void logAllBookmarkRows() {
        String hasval = " and has a value of ";
        String[] columns = new String[]{"*"};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Table ").append(TBL_BOOKMARK)
                .append(" has ")
                .append(String.valueOf(csr.getCount()))
                .append(" rows. The are :-");
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            sb.append("\n ROW ").append(String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_ID)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COl_NAME)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COl_HIDDEN)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(String.valueOf(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_HIDDEN)) > 0));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN").append(COL_ICON)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_NATIVEURL)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_SEARCHURL)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL)));
        }
        csr.close(); //<<<<< Should ALWAYS close a Cursor when done with it.
        Log.d("BOOKMARKDATA",sb.toString());
    }
}
```

- see the comments and perhaps have a look at [SQLiteOpenhelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper) and [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase)

In an activity you :-

1. Create an instance of the above class passing the Context
2. Use the methods of the instantiated BookmarkDBHelper object

e.g. :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BookmarkDBHelper mDBhlpr; // Declare the mDBHlpr object

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDBhlpr = new BookmarkDBHelper(this); // Instantiate mDBHlpr
        mDBhlpr.addBookMark(1,"Coogle",false,"coogle","www.coogle.notcom","https://www.coogle.notcom");
        mDBhlpr.addBookMark(2,"Bong",true,"bong","","https://www.bong.net");
        mDBhlpr.logAllBookmarkRows();
    }
}
```

- The above adds 2 (first run) rows to the bookmark table and then uses the logAllBookMarkRows to then extract the data from the database writing the results to the log.

### Result

```
2019-01-09 07:09:26.817 2112-2112/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor D/BOOKMARKDATA: Table bookmark has 2 rows. The are :-
     ROW 1
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 1
        COLUMN name and has a value of Coogle
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of coogle
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of www.coogle.notcom
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.coogle.notcom
     ROW 2
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 2
        COLUMN name and has a value of Bong
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of true
        COLUMNicon and has a value of bong
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.bong.net
```

**Note** this is intended solely as a guide to getting you to the stage where in-principle you can create an SQLite database, save data and retrieve data in order to answer :-

> I don't know how to create a SQLite db which will retrieve data and I
>   can save there new entry.

**You will undoubtedly have to adapt the above to suit** such as (but not limited to) perhaps altering the **addBookmark** method to take a **BookMark** as a parameter.

#### Note

If the above were run a second time it would work and produce the same output BUT the two rows would not be added as the id's would be the same (_id INTEGER PRIMARY implies a UNQIUE constraint). 2 exceptions would be raised but trapped and the log would include something similar to :-

```
2019-01-09 07:30:51.736 2295-2295/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Coogle icon=coogle searchurl=https://www.coogle.notcom _id=1 hidden=false nativeurl=www.coogle.notcom
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: bookmark._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.BookmarkDBHelper.addBookMark(BookmarkDBHelper.java:70)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-01-09 07:30:51.738 2295-2295/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Bong icon=bong searchurl=https://www.bong.net _id=2 hidden=true nativeurl=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: bookmark._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.BookmarkDBHelper.addBookMark(BookmarkDBHelper.java:70)
        at ptfc.populatetablefromcursor.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3049)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
```

### Additional

As per the comment *You need to extract the rows from the database (see the logAllBookmarks how to get the data) into an ArrayList (i.e. your arrayList).*

To suit the DB code the BookMark class has been changed to :-

```
public class Bookmark {
    String name, id, nativeUrl, searchUrl;
    long db_id; //<<<<<<<<< ADDED should really use long for id's
    String icon_name; //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    int icon;
    int viewType; //<<<<<<<<<< COLUMN HIDDEN in DB

    // ADDED as needed because empty contructor only exists by default if no other constructors exist
    public Bookmark() {
    }

    public Bookmark(long dbid, String name, String icon_name, String nativeUrl, String searchUrl, int hidden ) {

        this.db_id = dbid;
        this.id = String.valueOf(db_id);
        this.name = name;
        this.icon_name = icon_name;
        //<<<<<<<<<< ....... Shoud get icon id and set it here
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
        this.viewType = hidden;
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< START Of NEW GETTERS AND SETTERS
    public void setDb_id(long db_id) {
        this.db_id = db_id;
    }

    public long getDb_id() {
        return db_id;
    }

    public void setIcon_name(String icon_name) {
        this.icon_name = icon_name;
    }

    public String getIcon_name() {
        return icon_name;
    }
    //<<<<<<<<<< END OF NEW GETTERS AND SETTERS


    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIcon() { return icon; }
    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.db_id = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }

    public String getNativeUrl() {
        return nativeUrl;
    }

    public void setNativeUrl(String nativeUrl) {
        this.nativeUrl = nativeUrl;
    }

    public String getSearchUrl() {
        return searchUrl;
    }

    public void setSearchUrl(String searchUrl) {
        this.searchUrl = searchUrl;
    }
    public int getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public void setViewType(int viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookmark{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", icon='" + icon + '\'' +
                ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", nativeUrl='" + nativeUrl + '\'' +
                ", searchUrl='" + searchUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** see comments as you may have some issue with viewType

Now the following method, added to the DatabseHelper **BookmarDBHelper.java**, will return an ArrayList of Bookmarks from the database:-

```
public ArrayList<Bookmark> getAllBookmarks() {
    ArrayList<Bookmark> rv  = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(new Bookmark(
                csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)),
                csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL)),
                csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_HIDDEN))
        ));
    }
    return rv;
}

- Note if no rows exists then the returned ArrayList will have a size of 0.
```

An example use (as if the activity above) "-

```
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrylist = mDBhlpr.getAllBookmarks();
    for (Bookmark b: arrylist) {
        Log.d("BOOKMARKFROMLIST",b.toString());
    }
```

Results in :-

```
2019-01-09 12:30:44.663 1701-1701/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor D/BOOKMARKFROMLIST: Bookmark{name='Coogle', icon='0', id='1', nativeUrl='www.coogle.notcom', searchUrl='https://www.coogle.notcom'}
2019-01-09 12:30:44.665 1701-1701/ptfc.populatetablefromcursor D/BOOKMARKFROMLIST: Bookmark{name='Bong', icon='0', id='2', nativeUrl='', searchUrl='https://www.bong.net'}
```

Comment: Yeah this is working to save and in Logs shows me the rows but aren't showing in Fragment Bookmark class do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @Spritzig You need to extract the rows from the database (*see the logAllBookmarks how to get the data*) into an ArrayList<Bookmark> (i.e. your **arrayList**). So add a method to **BookmarkDBhelper** that does this (based upon logAllBookmarks) with a signature like `public class ArrayList<Bookmark> getBookmarks()`{... the body of the method ...}.

Comment: Can you provide a little code to give me a direction for this ?

Comment: @Spritzig SO works with specific questions being asked, some giving their time answering being rewarded by being upvoted and or ticked. I believe that I as per* I don't know how to create a SQLite db which will retrieve data and I can save there new entry.* I have answered but not been rewarded. So what incentive is their for myself to go beyond and become a code writing service? Perhaps if I am rewarded then I will consider amending the answer. Although I would be more likely to answer another question perhaps ***How do I build an ArrayList<Bookmark> from data stored in an SQLite Database***

Comment: I understand you and I have made you answer as accepted but you didn't write the code how to show saved bookmarks in my Fragment.
In Fragment show me the data from parsed xml and data from sqlite.

Comment: the viewType does not have nothing to do with bookmark list that shows bookmarks and a button which depends on the list of bookmark.

Comment: Would you help me on this if I create another question ?

Comment: @Spritzig that's what I said I may do. I'm not making any promises though. Fragments and Recyclerview are my most favourite topics.

Comment: @Spritzig too much code to go in the answer, so added another answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Additional - getting it working within the fragment (sort of)

#### As per comments

> I understand you and I have made you answer as accepted but you didn't
>   write the code how to show saved bookmarks in my Fragment. In Fragment
>   show me the data from parsed xml and data from sqlite.

The following based upon your code loads the database and populates the arraylist for the RecyclerView.

**Bookmark.java** is as per your Bookmar.java not the one previously used in the question.

**BookmarkDBHelper.java** used is amended (main change is that **getAllBookmarks** has been incoporated) from above and is :-

```
public class BookmarkDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "bookmarks.db"; // The name of the database file
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;  // The Database version

    public static final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
    public static final String COl_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COl_HIDDEN = "hidden";
    public static final String COL_ICON = "icon";
    public static final String COL_NATIVEURL = "nativeurl";
    public static final String COL_SEARCHURL = "searchurl";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public BookmarkDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        // Forces creation of the database (if it doesn't already exist)
        // and stores it when the BookmarkDBHelpr is instantiated
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * This creates the table(s) NOTE only automatically runs once
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // The SQL to be used to create the table
        String crt_bookmark_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BOOKMARK + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_HIDDEN + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_ICON + " TEXT, " +
                COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT," +
                COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_bookmark_tbl_sql); // CREATE THE TABLE

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    /**
     * Adds a row
     */
    public long addBookMark(long id, String name, boolean hidden, String icon, String nativeurl, String searchurl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COl_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COl_HIDDEN,hidden);
        cv.put(COL_ICON,icon);
        cv.put(COL_NATIVEURL,nativeurl);
        cv.put(COL_SEARCHURL,searchurl);
        // uses the convenience insert method that builds the SQL
        return mDB.insert(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,cv);
    }

    public ArrayList<Bookmark> getAllBookmarks() {
        ArrayList<Bookmark> rv  = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmark b = new Bookmark();
            b.setId(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            b.setName(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            b.setIcon(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON)));
            b.setViewType(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            b.setNativeUrl(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
            b.setSearchUrl(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL)));
            rv.add(b);
        }
        return rv;
    }


    /**
     * Example of extracting data from the database
     */
    public void logAllBookmarkRows() {
        String hasval = " and has a value of ";
        String[] columns = new String[]{"*"};
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Table ").append(TBL_BOOKMARK)
                .append(" has ")
                .append(String.valueOf(csr.getCount()))
                .append(" rows. The are :-");
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            sb.append("\n ROW ").append(String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_ID)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(String.valueOf(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COl_NAME)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COl_HIDDEN)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(String.valueOf(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_HIDDEN)) > 0));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN").append(COL_ICON)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_NATIVEURL)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
            sb.append("\n\tCOLUMN ").append(COL_SEARCHURL)
                    .append(hasval)
                    .append(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL)));
        }
        csr.close(); //<<<<< Should ALWAYS close a Cursor when done with it.
        Log.d("BOOKMARKDATA",sb.toString());
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java** (not tested or changed, I skipped trying to get the RecyclerView working as there's too much code layouts etc that isn't available).

**FragmentBoomark.java**

**Note** The work is all done in the **onAttach** method negating the need for the **onCreateView** to work (so it doesn't work but).

There are a few additional methods that are invoked. Note that some are purely for debugging/testing. Added methods added are :-

- **loadBookMarksFromXML**

  - loads the database from bookmark.xml (basically a copy of your code but it loads to the DB first **IF there are no rows in the DB**).
- **buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB**

  - Builds **arraylist** as per comment change the DB then this should be called and the RecyclerView needs to be refreshed (notifydatasetChanged I think or an equivalent)

You notice that some code has been commented out the XML parsing (probably leave this commented out), other code primarily to negate the need for writing/guessing other code.

:-

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {

    BookmarkDBHelper mDB;

    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    View paramView;
    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private Context mContext;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
        mDB = new BookmarkDBHelper(mContext);
        mDB.logAllBookmarkRows();
        loadBookMarksFromXML();
        buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB();
        mDB.logAllBookmarkRows();

    }
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        myRecyclerView =  paramView.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 4));
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        /* MOVED
        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"),"drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);
                        arrayList.add(bookmark);
                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
        bookmark.setViewType(1);
        //bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);
        arrayList.add(bookmark);
        return paramView;
    }


    private void loadBookMarksFromXML() {

        // MAY WISH TO ONLY DO THIS ONCE as bookmarks would be loaded OTHERWISE DELETE LINE BELOW
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDB.getWritableDatabase(),BookmarkDBHelper.TBL_BOOKMARK) > 0 ) return;
        try {
            XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.bookmarks);
            while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Bookmark")) {
                        Bookmark bookmark = new Bookmark();
                        bookmark.setName(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "name"));
                        bookmark.setSearchUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "searchUrl"));
                        bookmark.setNativeUrl(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "nativeUrl"));
                        int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "icon"),"drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
                        bookmark.setIcon(drawableResourceId);
                        bookmark.setViewType(0);
                        if (bookmark.getId() == null) {
                            bookmark.setId("-1");
                        }
                        mDB.addBookMark(
                                Long.valueOf(bookmark.getId()),
                                bookmark.getName(),
                                bookmark.getViewType() > 0,
                                String.valueOf(bookmark.getIcon()),
                                bookmark.getNativeUrl(),
                                bookmark.getSearchUrl()
                        );
                    }
                }
                xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mDB.logAllBookmarkRows();
    }

    // CALL ME WHENEVER BOOKMARKS change
    private void buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB() {
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(mDB.getAllBookmarks());
    }
}
```

### Results

- (note **NPE** at end is when createView gets run (as previously stated too much to do to get this running based upon guesswork))

:-

```
2019-01-11 13:00:58.405 8021-8021/so54090082.so54090082 D/BOOKMARKDATA: Table bookmark has 0 rows. The are :-
2019-01-11 13:00:58.415 8021-8021/so54090082.so54090082 D/BOOKMARKDATA: Table bookmark has 13 rows. The are :-
     ROW 1
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 1
        COLUMN name and has a value of Bing
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.bing.com
     ROW 2
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 2
        COLUMN name and has a value of Google
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.google.com
     ROW 3
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 3
        COLUMN name and has a value of Youtube
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://m.youtube.com
     ROW 4
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 4
        COLUMN name and has a value of Facebook
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of facebook://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://m.facebook.com
     ROW 5
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 5
        COLUMN name and has a value of Twitter
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://mobile.twitte.com
     ROW 6
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 6
        COLUMN name and has a value of Instagram
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of instagram://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://instagram.com
     ROW 7
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 7
        COLUMN name and has a value of Gmail
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of googlemail://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://gmail.com
     ROW 8
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 8
        COLUMN name and has a value of Translate
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://
     ROW 9
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 9
        COLUMN name and has a value of Amazon
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.amazon.com
     ROW 10
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 10
        COLUMN name and has a value of Wikipedia
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page
     ROW 11
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 11
        COLUMN name and has a value of Weather
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://weather.com
     ROW 12
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 12
        COLUMN name and has a value of eBay
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://ebay.to/1VPVeAs
     ROW 13
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 13
        COLUMN name and has a value of Apple
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://www.apple.com
2019-01-11 13:00:58.418 8021-8021/so54090082.so54090082 D/BOOKMARKDATA: Table bookmark has 13 rows. The are :-
     ROW 1
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 1
        COLUMN name and has a value of Bing
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.bing.com
     ROW 2
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 2
        COLUMN name and has a value of Google
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.google.com
     ROW 3
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 3
        COLUMN name and has a value of Youtube
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://m.youtube.com
     ROW 4
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 4
        COLUMN name and has a value of Facebook
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of facebook://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://m.facebook.com
     ROW 5
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 5
        COLUMN name and has a value of Twitter
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://mobile.twitte.com
     ROW 6
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 6
        COLUMN name and has a value of Instagram
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of instagram://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://instagram.com
     ROW 7
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 7
        COLUMN name and has a value of Gmail
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of googlemail://
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://gmail.com
     ROW 8
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 8
        COLUMN name and has a value of Translate
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://
     ROW 9
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 9
        COLUMN name and has a value of Amazon
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.amazon.com
     ROW 10
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 10
        COLUMN name and has a value of Wikipedia
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page
     ROW 11
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 11
        COLUMN name and has a value of Weather
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://weather.com
     ROW 12
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 12
        COLUMN name and has a value of eBay
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://ebay.to/1VPVeAs
     ROW 13
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 13
        COLUMN name and has a value of Apple
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of null
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of http://www.apple.com
2019-01-11 13:00:58.434 8021-8021/so54090082.so54090082 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-01-11 13:00:58.436 8021-8021/so54090082.so54090082 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: so54090082.so54090082, PID: 8021
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at so54090082.so54090082.ui.fragmentbookmark.FragmentBookmark.onCreateView(FragmentBookmark.java:53)
```

### Results of a subsequent run (i.e. data has been previously loaded) :-

```
2019-01-11 13:09:29.363 8159-8159/so54090082.so54090082 D/BOOKMARKDATA: Table bookmark has 13 rows. The are :-
     ROW 1
        COLUMN _id and has a value of 1
        COLUMN name and has a value of Bing
        COLUMN hidden and has a value of false
        COLUMNicon and has a value of 0
        COLUMN nativeurl and has a value of 
        COLUMN searchurl and has a value of https://www.bing.com
..........
```

Comment: This works, but i am able to see only the new data from sqlite the data from parsed xml and when new Data is saved I need to restart the app then it will appear the saved item.

Comment: @Spritzig See the comment re **// CALL ME WHENEVER BOOKMARKS change** So dave data, call **buildBookmarkArrayListfromDB()** and then do **notifydatasetChanged** (I think, as I said not very conversant with RecyclerView). I personally tend to use Cursor adapters with ListViews. Saving, updating, deleting is what I meant by database/bookmarks changed.

Comment: I would ask something and please let me know if you can, it takes only the Bing from parsed xml the others no.
And the icon for new entrys it need to take the favicon from the website url.
Do you know how to do that ?
Can you please create a complete code with SQLite my Fragment and the adapter of recyclerview.

Comment: The error in Fragment in the load method is is coming like this.
`Error inserting name=Google icon=2131165327 searchurl=https://www.google.com _id=-1 hidden=false nativeurl=
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: bookmark._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY)`
Only the bing it is added the others no.The error comes in this function
`mDB.addBookmark(Long.valueOf(bookmark.getId()),bookmark.getName(),                                bookmark.getViewType() > 0,String.valueOf(bookmark.getIcon()),bookmark.getNativeUrl(), bookmark.getSearchUrl());`

Comment: @Spritzig if you look **_id**'s value is **-1** and is therefore being set (all are being set to -1 hence only 1 row). The **addBookmark method** has been amended (forgot to post the latest code in the answer) to remove 3 lines that include the line **`cv.put(COL_ID,id); // NOTE will not insert if id already exists.`**. This was based upon the assumption that XMLParser code set correct value of the bookmark object. It doesn't and hence why all end up with -1. As such removing **put**ting the _id value allows SQLite to generate a unique value.

Comment: @Spritzig No idea how to get favicon.

Comment: I have worked around with Bitmap but I am not taking in the right, what I want is something like this, take the url from searchUrl and /favicon.ico but I cannot convert to int.

Comment: at the Fragment you have commented the `bookmark.setIcon(R.drawable.add_new_bookmark_icon);` I need to show this button in the Fragment and when I comment to show it is not showing me anymore, do you know why ?

Comment: I commented it out to simplify providing the answer (no hassle having to deal with images, I primarily provide answers based upon my experience with SQLite presentation/user interface is not my forte at all)

Comment: Well, I will try to find a way because now it is not showing my code even If I write to show this Icon.